# Does a homomorphism send a subgroup to itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $P$ be a normal $p$-Sylow subgroup of a finite group G and let $\phi:G \to G$ be a homomorphism. Is it necessarily true that the elements of $P$ will also get mapped within the subgroup, $\phi: P \to P$? That is, can we say that for any element $p \in P, \phi(p) \in P$, too?

As a note, I'm aware that in the end it does turn out that $\phi(P) \subseteq P$. I'm wondering if we need to argue that thoroughly or if we can just say that the image of $P$ is a subset of $P$ because by definition of a homomorphism the elements will be mapped back to the subset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P$ is a normal $p$-Sylow subgroup, then you know it is the unique maximal $p$-subgroup of $G$ (because $p$-Sylow subgroups are conjugate to one another). Since any $p$-subgroup of $G$ is contained in a $p$-Sylow subgroup, we get that any $p$-subgroup of $G$ is contained in $P$.

So, let $\phi$ be an endomorphism of $G$. Then $\phi(P)$ is the homomorphic image of a $p$-group, hence it is a $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. So I think I understand why $\phi(P) \subseteq P$, but I want to make sure that that is as much as we know. For instance, we cannot say that if $s \in P, \phi(s) = s \in P$, correct? Like $\phi$ isn't given to be any sort of identity mapping so no definition of a homomorphism would imply that any element is necessarily mapped back to itself, right?

Comment: @Bryyo357 If $\phi$ is an automorphism, you can infer $\phi(P)=P$ for cardinality reasons. But just considering the trivial homomorphism $\phi(g)=1$, for all $g\in G$, tells you that not much more can be said. The fact that $P$ is self-conjugated doesn't mean that its elements are self-conjugate, so the elements of $P$ need not be fixed even by inner automorphisms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but in general only if $P$ is unique (i.e. if it is normal).

That's because in general $\operatorname{ord}(\phi(g)) \mid \operatorname{ord}(g)$ for every $g \in G$. Since for every $\pi \in P$ we have $\operatorname{ord}(\pi) = p^n$ for some $n \geq 0$, it follows that $\operatorname{ord}(\phi(\pi)) = p^m$ for some $0 \leq m \leq n$. Thus $\operatorname{ord}(\phi(\pi))$ lies in some $p$-Sylow subgroup, but we can't guarantee in which one unless it is unique.